# How can I use a variable from an external .js file in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

I've got a function that I've written that populates a URL (that contains an image) based on the browser language. This subsequent URL is then written to a variable. All the images are based on language, so for germany it will be "de.gif", France would be "fr.gif" and so on.

My question is how can I call this variable in my HTML page?

To help me to better illustrate this problem here is the JavaScript, please note this is an EXTERNAL .js file called in the  of this HTML page:

```
function IABEU_moused_detect() {
(function IAB_lang_detect() {"use strict";
var IAB_lang_map = {"de-at": "at","nl-be": "be-nl","fr-be": "be-fr","da": "den","de": "de","hu": "hu","en-ie": "ie","ga": "ie","es": "es","fr": "fr","it": "it","nl": "nl","no": "nor","pl": "pl","en": "uk","en-GB": "uk","en-US": "uk","en-gb": "uk","en-us": "uk"},
IAB_lang = (navigator && navigator.browserLanguage) || (window.navigator && window.navigator.language) || "en-GB";
IAB_url = ("http://www.someurl.com/" + IAB_lang_map[IAB_lang]);
IAB_img = ("http://www.myimagesarehere.com/" + IAB_lang_map[IAB_lang]+".gif");
}());}
```

So it's the IAB_img variable that I want to call in my HTML page (it's a global variable in the .js file)

The HTML is here:

```
<div>
  <img src="HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO call the variable 'IAB_img'"> 
</div>
```

Thanks

EDIT: So I still can't solve this, is there a way for me to use the value in "IAB_img" as the image src in my HTML file?

Comment: The more appropriate way of serving localized content is by inspecting the Accept-Language HTTP headers. The broser language property that can be inspected via Javascript reflects the language the browser was installed in, not the user's preferred language.

Comment: This is true I know. But I can't do this server side so I have been asked to implement it client side. I realise this is a "dirty" way of doing it but I don't have a choice

Comment: Can you edit the HTML also, or only the JavaScript?

Comment: I can edit the HTML too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by giving the image an id.

```
<div>
    <img id="TheImage" src="HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO call the variable 'IAB_img'"> 
</div>
```

Then in your JavaScript function, just assign the src of the image like so:

```
function IABEU_moused_detect() {
    (function IAB_lang_detect() {"use strict";
        var IAB_lang_map = {"de-at": "at","nl-be": "be-nl","fr-be": "be-fr","da": "den","de": "de","hu": "hu","en-ie": "ie","ga": "ie","es": "es","fr": "fr","it": "it","nl": "nl","no": "nor","pl": "pl","en": "uk","en-GB": "uk","en-US": "uk","en-gb": "uk","en-us": "uk"},
        IAB_lang = (navigator && navigator.browserLanguage) || (window.navigator &&   window.navigator.language) || "en-GB";
        IAB_url = ("http://www.someurl.com/" + IAB_lang_map[IAB_lang]);
        IAB_img = ("http://www.myimagesarehere.com/" + IAB_lang_map[IAB_lang]+".gif");
        var image = document.getElementById('TheImage');
        image.src = IAB_img;
}());}
```

Comment: Thanks @ptfaulkner but I don't think this achieves that I am after. I need the src of the image to be the string that is located in the variable "IAB_img".

Comment: Try putting a placeholder url in the img src in the HTML code.  Maybe there is an error preventing the assignment of the src in JavaScript.  You may also want to try the assignment in one line like: document.getElementById('TheImage').src = IAB_img;

Comment: Cool thanks @ptfaulkner. I've already got it on one line :) When I check in firebug I just get the error "Failed to load given URL)..

Comment: That sounds like the url in the IAB_img variable isn't correct.  Does it look correct in firebug?

Comment: Looks correct in Firebug, Ive also done a document.write(IAB_img) just to make sure that I can see the URL is being concatenated & assigned properly.

Comment: @Kiz I can confirm that ptfaulkner's solution works in an isolated environment: http://jsfiddle.net/BGzcb/. If this doesn't work, then the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: @YiJiang thanks. I still can't get it to work for some reason. The thing is I need the src of that image to be populated based on the value of "IAB_img". The Firefox console log is saying that the value of 'image' is null!

Comment: @Kiz If the value of `image` is null, then `document.getElementById` is not getting the element. Are you sure the `id` matches exactly, and is the script been run only after the DOM is loaded? (ie. place your script inside an `window.onload` event handler or place the `<script>` element at the end of `<body>`)

Comment: @YiJiang Aha, that may be the problem. The script is actually from an external .js file. Is this not possible?

Comment: @Kiz Like I said, place the `<script>` element that loads the external JavaScript file at the end of the `<body>` element

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4829/discussion-between-kiz-and-yi-jiang) - actually no need that sorted it :) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you rendering the html page via a template?  If so, you could include a javascript snippet with a variable setup to be read further on:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var IAB_img = {{value}};
</script>
```

Just put this before you load your other script, and then the IAB_img will already be defined for you.

Comment: Thanks - but it's not done via a template. The answer above solved it (after lots of deliberation by me) but thanks all the same

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
<div>
 <img src="javascript:document.write(IAB_img);" />
</div>
```

Comment: <script>document.write("<img src='" + IAB_img + "' />");</script>

Comment: This is entirely wrong. Inline JavaScript is only called if it is inside an inline event handler (like `onclick`), which `src` most certainly is not

Comment: So @Yi Jiang is what I am trying to do achievable?