# place javascript in html5 in external file

Tags: javascript, html

In html5 how do i place the class below (constructor and method)in another file and reference it in the html file.

Below I have everything in 1 file and I dont want that.

```
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font="14px Arial"; 



  //how to move to other file
  function ClassPerson(gender,name1) {
      var aa;
      this.gender=gender;
      this.name1=name1;
      aa=6;

  };

   //how to move to other file
  ClassPerson.prototype.m_sayGender = function()
    {
    ctx.fillText("this gender= " + this.gender + " gender=" + this.name1,10,40);
    };

    //stay in this file
  var person1 = new ClassPerson('male','dave');
  var person2 = new ClassPerson('female','bet');
  ctx.fillText("this gender= " + person1.gender,10,20);
  person1.m_sayGender();
  myObject._three();

</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply create an external JS file with your code
and include it like this:

`<script src="myFile.js"> </script>`
or

```
<script src="<myFile>.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Be sure to place the JS file in the directory where you have your HTML file

After comment: I guess you have to dynamically create an image with javacript set it's `src` porpertie and the diplay it.

Comment: ok that works but why did I get a -1 vote? My example was without an image which is what I wanted to ask. How do I access an image loaded in a class from another file using canvas/html5.

Comment: I cant ask another question and paste the code of what I am talking about? I cant get access to the image from a class.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050573/how-can-i-use-a-variable-from-an-external-js-file-in-my-html

Answer (score 0):

Set the whole JS code of your class in an external *.js file. Then import it into your *.html file like this:

```
<script src="<external-file-name>.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```