# JavaScript isn't loaded when using link element

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a website with JavaScript popups. Basically, when you click a link an alert or prompt comes up saying "You are now entering the [enter webpage name here] section."

For some reason, when I click the link, it will open the page but ignore *any* JavaScript! Here is the basic code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head><link rel="text/javascript" href="effects.js" /></head>
<body>
<a href="common_code.html" onclick = "common_lang();">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (effects.js):

```
function common_lang() {
    var enterCommon = prompt("You are now entering the Common Languages section.");
}
```

I don't get why this won't work! Does anyone have any ideas? Also, is there a way to make this more efficient? And I need the file in the same window so I can't use any window.open jazz. But efficiency isn't a priority, remember!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631635/can-i-load-javascript-code-using-link-tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [place javascript in html5 in external file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896704/place-javascript-in-html5-in-external-file)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `script` tag instead of `link`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="effects.js">
```

Comment: Is that for efficiency or the original question?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that, it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the `link` tag to `script` like:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="effects.js"></script>`

Second, this is because you are using the `href` attribute so the link just redirects you to `common_code.html`

if you want to navigate to the link based on user prompt selection you can do it like:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="common_lang();">Click here</a>`

```
function common_lang() {
    var enterCommon = prompt("You are now entering the            Common Languages section.");
    if(enterCommon) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = "common_code.html";
        a.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    }
}
```

Comment: When i do this, does it open in a new tab? Because I can't have that.

Comment: Also, when I do that script tag instead, does it still link to a separate file?

Comment: sure, you are using `link` when you want to load external css file, for scripts you need to use the `script` tag

Comment: here you go, see the new function body

Comment: I like the look of the code, it looks like it would work, thank you. I'll try it out as soon as I can.